# Getting the documentID of a Firestore document in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How do I get the generated documentID of a document in Firestore in Flutter?

I know I can access the various fields of a document like this:

```
    return Firestore().collection(postPath).data.documents.forEach((response) {
      nodeList.add(Post(
        // response.data().id - how do i get the UID (example: -LUoDIu4wlVksjbbfIWE)?
        response['content'],
        response['date'],
        response['flair'],
        response['location'],
        response['username'],
      ));
});
```

But I am unsure of the method to call get the UID of the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for documentId property.

```
String id = response.documentID;
```

If documentId property does not exist for your response object, update the cloud_firestore plugin to a newer version.

Comment: Thanks. I believe the property is `documentID` instead of `documentId`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634415/flutter-firestore-find-document-snapshot-id?rq=1

Comment: @Carrein Sorry, yeah you're right. I will edit that now.